# jQuery add or remove class when modal open/close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, thanks for reading. I don't know anything about jQuery or JavaScript, that's why I'm here.

Searching a little bit I found the code I want, but unfortunately the gallery I'm making has several elements, and this code doesn't work as I want.

This is the little script I have:

```js
function showImage(imgName) {
    var curImage = document.getElementById('currentImg');
    var thePath = '/images/full/';
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;
    curImage.src = theSource;
    curImage.alt = imgName;
}
```

```html
<span class="thumb_ef"><a href="#" class="activate_modal" name="first_window"><img src="images/thumb/image1.png" alt="Image One"/></a></span>
<span class="thumb_ef"><a href="#" class="activate_modal" name="second_window"><img src="images/thumb/image2.png" alt="Image Two"/></a></span>
<span class="thumb_ef"><a href="#" class="activate_modal" name="third_window"><img src="images/thumb/image3.png" alt="Image Three"/></a></span>

<div id="first_window" class="modal_window">
  
  <h2>Title here</h2>
  
  <div id="preview">
    <img id="currentImg" class="bigimg" src="images/full/image1.png" alt="images/full/image1.png">
  </div>
  
  <h3>Thumbnail preview</h3>
  
  <div id="thumb">
    <span class="thumb_mef"><img src="images/full/thumb_image1.png" alt="images/full/thumb_image1.png" onclick="showImage('image1.png');"></span>
    <span class="thumb_mef"><img src="images/full/thumb_image2.png" alt="images/full/thumb_image2.png" onclick="showImage('image2.png');"></span>
    <span class="thumb_mef"><img src="images/full/thumb_image3.png" alt="images/full/thumb_image3.png" onclick="showImage('image3.png');"></span>
    <span class="thumb_mef"><img src="images/full/thumb_image4.png" alt="images/full/thumb_image4.png" onclick="showImage('image4.png');"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Let me explain a little bit, because I'm not gonna put all the unnecesary code here.

In the gallery, I have several little images, when you click them, triggers a modal box with different ID for each image in order to load different content for each element.

Inside the modal, I have a title, a full-size image and four thumbnails preview images. This thumbnails images triggers the code I left before, loading the full-size image in the same ID when you click the thumbnail.

The problem I have is... I need to repeat this ID for the different modals, but if you want to click the thumbnails and load the full-size image of any other modal that's not the first, you don't gonna see the changes (Because the code works on the first ID).

I think the solution to this is add the ID (currentImg) only when the modal opens, and after remove this ID when the modal close, to solve the problem.

I don't know how to do that, and probably I need to mix both codes but again, I don't know anything about jQuery/Javascript, here's the modal code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var window_width = $(window).width();  
 var window_height = $(window).height();  

 $('.modal_window').each(function(){
  var modal_height = $(this).outerHeight();
 var modal_width = $(this).outerWidth();
  var top = (window_height-modal_height) / 2;  
  var left = (window_width-modal_width) / 2;  
  $(this).css({'top' : top , 'left' : left});  
 });  
   
 $('.activate_modal').click(function(){  
  var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');  
  show_modal(modal_id);
 });  
   
 $('.close_modal').click(function(){  
  close_modal();  
 }); 

 function close_modal(){  
  $('#mask').fadeOut(500);  
  $('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);  
 }

 function show_modal(modal_id){  
  $('#mask').css({ 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0});
  $('#mask').fadeTo(500,0.8);  
  $('#'+modal_id).fadeIn(500);  
 }
});
```

Hope you can understand, my native language isn't english, please tell me if you don't understand.

Comment: p/s: Java !== JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks but if you read what I wrote, you're gonna understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: The only thing I need was to search the ID of the modal box, then search the class of the img element and add an ID to that. After this, on the close modal event, remove any ID from the img class.

This is the final result:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var window_width = $(window).width();  
  var window_height = $(window).height();  

  $('.modal_window').each(function(){
      var modal_height = $(this).outerHeight();  
      var modal_width = $(this).outerWidth();  
      var top = (window_height-modal_height) / 2;  
      var left = (window_width-modal_width) / 2;  
      $(this).css({'top' : top , 'left' : left});  
  });  
   
  $('.activate_modal').click(function(){  
   var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');  
   show_modal(modal_id);
   $('#'+modal_id).find('.bigimg').attr('id', 'currentImg');
  });  
   
  $('.close_modal').click(function(){
   $('.bigimg').removeAttr('id');
   close_modal();
  }); 

  function close_modal(){  
      $('#mask').fadeOut(500);  
      $('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);  
  }

  function show_modal(modal_id){  
      $('#mask').css({ 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0});
      $('#mask').fadeTo(500,0.8);  
      $('#'+modal_id).fadeIn(500);
  }
 });
```